# Is the Prophet Malachi the same person as Ezra Hasofer?

Tags: names, tanach, ezra-the-scribe

I saw in a few places that when they write Malachi, in parentheses they write Ezra. Does that mean that some people agree that they are one person?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is such an opinion in the Talmud ([Megillah 15a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Megillah.15a.5?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi)):

> "It is taught in a baraita: Rabbi Yehoshua ben Korḥa said: Malachi is in fact Ezra."

This view has been accepted by many, although there are those that disagree, including right there in the Talmud.

Comment: So what should I teach my students? What is the most accepted idea?

Comment: @Sarah I'm not a teacher. It's up to you, really, although there's always the third option: "...and there are many that say that Ezra is Malachi etc". You know - sort of neutral. But I've heard great classes about the character of Ezra based on either view - some that hold he was Malachi and some that hold that he wasn't. Holding that he wasn't doesn't diminish his character.

Comment: The gemara there also brings a second opinion that malachi hanovi could also be mordechai from the purim story and a third opinion that he is neither ezra hasofer or mordechai. interesting to note that the traditional yahrtzeit of ezra hasofer is 9 teves while malachi is said to have been niftar on 10 teves, this may suggest they are different characters

Comment: @ezra or he died bein hashemashot

Comment: @ezra True. I alluded to other options at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The rabbis are not unanimous regarding Malachi's identity. While some indeed think he is the same person as Ezra, Rav Nahman says he is Mordecai.

Megillah 15a

> Rav Naḥman said: Malachi the prophet is in fact Mordecai, and why was
> he called Malachi? To indicate that he was second to the king
> [melekh], as Mordecai was appointed such, as is recorded at the end of
> the Megilla.

Sanhedrin 11a treats him as a distinct individual

> The Sages taught: After the last of the prophets, Haggai, Zechariah,
> and Malachi, died, the Divine Spirit of prophetic revelation departed
> from the Jewish people.

A third possibility is that Malachi was simply an otherwise unknown prophet. [Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1678766/jewish/Who-Was-the-Prophet-Malachi.htm) identifies him as "a member of the Great Assembly during the beginning of the second Jewish commonwealth [who] was considered the last Jewish prophet."

**Conclusion**: The Prophet Malachi is not necessarily the same person as Ezra Hasofer.